# Android Studio 2.4 + Lombok annotationProcessor configuration confusion

Tags: android, android-studio, lombok, annotation-processing, android-studio-2.4

I using lombok on some project, and with the new Android Studio 2.4 Update now (Preview) I get this strange error:

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task
>   ':core:javaPreCompileRelease'. Annotation processors must be
>   explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile
>   classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them
>   to the annotationProcessor configuration.
>       - lombok-1.16.16.jar   Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath
>   = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.   See
>   https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html
>   for more details.

I already tried:

> annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16"

but has no effect.

I also tested:

> android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath
>   = true

But also has no effect.

Also checked the support page for further information but with no luck, anyone of you possibly?
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/index.html?utm_source=android-studio#annotationProcessor_config

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update:

```
provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16" // keep
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16" // add this
```

Just worked perfectly, but I have two Android Studio modules, and **two build.gradle** files.
The error log just changed a bit (module prefix), and I thought the fix didn't work.

But after applying the fix to **both build.gradle** files everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Had the same problem. I was using Lombok in an Android lib module and a Java lib module. I only had to update build.gradle in the Android module. The Java module can stay as `compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:[YOUR VERSION]"`

Comment: With Android Studio 3.0 canary 1 in addition to the above provided/annotationProcessor rows I had to add also 
`javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath = true
            }
        }`
inside the
`android {
  defaultConfig{
  }
}` section.

Comment: `annotationProcessor` should be `kapt`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but needed a slightly different fix (although the idea came from the accepted answer above - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43820494/1777346)

Turned out I already had the provided and annotationProcessor in both build.gradle files.. but, I also had a compile entry. Removing it fixed this issue for me:

```
compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16' // remove this
provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16'
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16"
```

Just figured I'd add my findings in case it helps anyone. I'm using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4 and gradle:3.0.0-alpha4 in my unending quest to get build times down.. which never seems to pay off :)